# Using Easy RDF in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, rdf

I have to use Easy RDF library in my Laravel 5.1 project and I have some problem. I've added this library to my composer.json file, installed it, and now I have this code:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $foaf = new EasyRdf_Graph("http://biblioteka.wejherowo.pl/dlibra/dlibra/rdf.xml?type=e&id=1589");
        $foaf->load();
        $me = $foaf->primaryTopic();
        dd($me->get('dc:title'));
    }
```

But when I am trying to display something I get error about format, do i have to configure this library?

Here is the screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since this graph URI cannot be loaded even with a format hint `rdfxml` as a 3rd parameter in the ctor, try to load it indirectly:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://biblioteka.wejherowo.pl/dlibra/dlibra/rdf.xml?type=e&id=1589');
$parser = new EasyRdf_Parser_RdfXml();
$graph = new EasyRdf_Graph();
$parser->parse($graph, $file, 'rdfxml', null);
print $graph->dump('text');
```

This does, however, not answer your question about the format error.

Comment: Thank you! That works for me. But I have one more question. For example for this RDF file: http://biblioteka.wejherowo.pl/dlibra/dlibra/rdf.xml?type=e&id=1589 - how I can get value of this tag:

<dc:language xml:lang="pl">pol</dc:language>? :)